# Not able to load web PDF file which doesn't have .pdf at the end of the URL

Tags: pdfbox

I am using the below code for PDFBOX to read web pdf file

```
PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("http://<website name>/flow.html?operatorin"));
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String doc = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);
pddDocument.close();
System.out.println(doc);
```

So in the above code if you see url it is not showing as normal web pdf url with .pdf at the end.

How can we handle such cases?

Comment: Are you sure it's a url issue, and not content type?

Comment: try `new URL("url").openStream()` (this is simplified, you also need to close the stream when done)

Comment: .load method is not supporting URL it is saying that it only supports file

Comment: And also if i use open stream method and try to access through URL it is giving me IO error error end of file expected line

Comment: load() supports InputStream and `new URL("url").openStream()` returns an input stream. The error "IO error error end of file expected line" means the file is empty or not a PDF. Maybe your URL loads some HTML that has javascript.